# Rationality of curve does not depend on base change

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, fields, rational-curves, genus

By a *curve* I mean an integral one-dimensional scheme of finite type over a spectrum of a field.

Let $C$ be a curve over an arbitrary field $k$. It's probably a very well known fact, that $C$ is rational over $k$, if and only if $C$ is rational over any field extension $L/k$. I'm wondering, if there an elementary proof of this property.

The easiest argument I can think about at this moment, is to choose a smooth projective curve $\overline{C}\subset\mathbb{P}_k^n$ birational to $C$ and observe, that it's Hilbert polynomial does not depend on base extension $L/k$. This is a consequence of the fact that $L$ is a flat $k$-module. Therefore, the arithmetic genus of $C$ does not depend on base extension. Finally, by Bézout theorem and the genus formula, one can verify that arithmetic genus equal to zero implies that there exist a $k$-parametrization $\mathbb{P}_k^1\longrightarrow\overline{C}$.

All this said, I believe that there should exist a shorter and more algebraic argument. However, I can't find one. I will be grateful for any piece of advice.

**EDIT** As @Abhinav pointed out in his answer below, the statement is not even true in general. Luckily for me, it holds true as long as the field extension $L/k$ is pure transcendental (see the answer of @Pete L. Clark below), which is good enough for the applications I was thinking about. Thank you! :)

Comment: The argument fails at the last step: you need a $k$-rational point on $\overline{C}$ to carry this step out (if I understand you correctly) and such a point may not exist.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of :) Hopefully, in my particular use-case I can prove that $C$ has enough $k$-rational points.

Comment: Actually, I only need this lemma in case when $L$ is a pure transcendental extension of $k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, why not turn my comment on Abhinav's answer into an answer?
$\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}$
$\newcommand{\PP}{\mathbb{P}}$
$\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}}$

This is a cut-and-paste from a passage in a paper I wrote earlier today.

> Lemma: 
>   Let $L/K$ be a purely transcendental field extension.
>   a) Let $V_{/K}$ be an algebraic variety.  Suppose *either* that $K$ is infinite or $V$ is complete.  Then $V(L) \neq \varnothing \implies V(K) \ \neq \varnothing$.
>   b) For every abelian variety $A_{/K}$, we have $H^1(L/K,A) = 0$.

Proof: a) 
Step 1: Let $\{t_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a transcendence basis for $L/K$.  If $P \in V(L)$, there is a finite subset $J \subset I$ such that $P \in V( K(\{t_i\}_{i \in J})$.  Thus we are 
reduced to the case in which $L/K$ has finite transcendence degree.  Induction  reduces us to the case $L = K(t)$.
Step 2: A point $P \in V(K(t))$ corresponds to a rational map $\varphi: \mathbb{P}^1 \ra V$.  The locus on which $\varphi$ is not defined is a finite set of closed points of $\mathbb{P}^1$.  If $K$ is infinite, so is $\mathbb{P}^1(K)$, and thus there is $P \in \mathbb{P}^1(K)$ at which $\varphi$ 
is defined, and then $\varphi(P) \in V(K)$.  On the other hand, any rational map from a regular curve to a complete variety is a morphism, so if $V$ is complete then 
e.g. $\varphi(0) \in V(K)$.
b) Since $\eta \in H^1(K,A)$ corresponds to a torsor $V$ under $A$ and thus a 
projective variety, this follows immediately from part a).

> Remark: 
>   a) If in the statement of the Lemmma we strengthen "complete" to "projective", a more elementary proof can be given: let $\varphi: V \ra \mathbb{P}^N$ be a $K$-embedding.  Since $K(t)$ is the fraction field of 
>   the UFD $K[t]$, if $P \in V(L)$, we can write $\varphi(P) = [f_0(t):\ldots:f_N(t)]$ with $\operatorname{gcd}(f_0,\ldots,f_N) = 1$.  In particular, some $f_i(t)$ is not divisible by $t$ and thus $(f_0(0):\ldots:f_N(0)) \in V(K)$.
>   b) Let $K = \F_q$ be a finite field.  Then the affine curve $V = \PP^1_{\F_q} \setminus \PP^1(\F_q)$ has $K(t)$-rational points but no $K$-rational points.

There follows (in the manuscript) a result that if you start with $V_{/K}$ and replace $K$ by the function field $K(X)$ of a variety $X_{/K}$ with a rational zero-cycle of degree $1$, the least degree of a rational zero-cycle on $V$ does not change.  Even this result is rather well-known, I think, but it can be hard to find these types of things written down in "proper generality".

Also the OP mentions something about his genus zero curve $C_{/K}$ having enough rational points to be rational.  For this: it is not hard to show that a geometrically integral curve of arithmetic genus $0$ over an arbitrary field is birational to $\mathbb{P}^1$ if and only if it has at least one nonsingular $K$-rational point.  By Riemann-Roch the curve is birational to a conic, and having a nonsingular rational point is a birational invariant (think in terms of valuations on the function field).

Comment: The $H^1(L|K,A)$ in part $b)$ is mysterious: the extension $L|K$ is not galois !

Comment: @Chandan: It means the kernel of the restriction map from $H^1(K,A)$ to $H^1(L,A)$, which is defined for any field extension.  (Anyway, it is has little to do with the OP's question, so should perhaps best be ignored or deleted.)

Answer (score 18):

If you're taking the definition of rational to be: birational to $\mathbb{P}^1$ over the field $k$, then the stated property is not even true. There are conics which have no rational points, and so are not rational, but are rational over a quadratic extension. For example, the affine conic $x^2 + y^2 + 1 = 0$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}$.

Added: since you only need the result when $L/k$ is a pure trancendental extension - there the result is indeed true. The idea is that you can represent any genus $0$ curve as a conic (take the embedding corresponding to $-K_C$), and so you need to show that if the conic has a rational point over a pure transcendental extension of $k$, then it has a rational point over $k$ itself. There are many ways to see this (essentially you specialize the indeterminates suitably so that no denominators vanish) - one way is by induction on the transcendence degree. For a reference see Lam's "Quadratic forms over fields", Lemma 1.1 of Chapter IX. The result holds more generally for quadratic forms in any number of variables.

Comment: That's a funny coincidence.  Earlier today I wrote up a proof of the following Lemma: Let $K$ be a field and $L/K$ a purely transcendental field extension.  Let $V_{/K}$ be a variety.  If either $K$ is infinite or $V$ is complete, then $V(L) \neq \varnothing \implies V(K) \neq \varnothing$.  The proof is not at all hard, but it becomes easier if you strengthen "complete" to "projective", as you note.  Note that *some*  hypothesis is needed to rule out things like $\mathbb{P}^1_{/\mathbb{F}_p} \setminus \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{F}_p)$!